# How can I check if port is busy in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I check if **port is busy** for `localhost`?

Is there any standard algorithm? I am thinking at making a `http` request to that url and check if response status code is not `404`.

Comment: https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder

Comment: portfinder is great :) just to mention, it has default port option: `portfinder.getPortPromise({port: 3000})...`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could attempt to start a server, either TCP or HTTP, it doesn't matter. Then you could try to start listening on a port, and if it fails, check if the error code is `EADDRINUSE`.

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();

server.once('error', function(err) {
  if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
    // port is currently in use
  }
});

server.once('listening', function() {
  // close the server if listening doesn't fail
  server.close();
});

server.listen(/* put the port to check here */);
```

With the single-use event handlers, you could wrap this into an asynchronous check function.

Comment: This doesn't work with servers that aren't using `SO_REUSEADDR`. Check out https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner to see how they used `net.Socket()` to work around this.

Comment: you should also wait till the server closes... by listening to the server close event `server.once('close', () => { myFunc() }).close()`

Comment: Launching a temporary server like this could lead to bad race conditions in multithreaded environments (e.g. Jest test-runner). Imagine if one thread launches a temporary server, while at the same time another thread tries to launch a "permanent" test-server. At this point, things could go haywire pretty fast.

Comment: you need to make sure what ip is listen in cace you have multiple ips running

Answer (score 16):

Check out the amazing [tcp-port-used node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-port-used)!

```
//Check if a port is open
tcpPortUsed.check(port [, host]) 

 //Wait until a port is no longer being used
tcpPortUsed.waitUntilFree(port [, retryTimeMs] [, timeOutMs])

//Wait until a port is accepting connections
tcpPortUsed.waitUntilUsed(port [, retryTimeMs] [, timeOutMs])

//and a few others!
```

I've used these to great effect with my [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) `watch` tasks for detecting when my Express server has been safely terminated and when it has spun up again.

This will accurately report whether a port is bound or not (regardless of `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT`, as mentioned by @StevenVachon).

The [portscanner NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portscanner) will find free and used ports for you within ranges and is more useful if you're trying to find an open port to bind.

Comment: This solution caused a lot of trouble in my prod environment `tcpPortUsed`  shows port as in use when listening port answer to telnet. I've a service accepting only one connection and refuse telnet. In such case it returns port is not in use.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz sorry to hear - can you explain? `tcpPortUsed` tries to make a TCP connection (not telnet - although telnet does the same thing) to the port. If it is able to make a connection, then the port is in use. If it is not, then the port is free. So I am not sure what you mean - a service can't know if a TCP connection is from telnet or from anything else until it accepts it.

Comment: That's what I'm exactly talking about. In my TCP Server application I limited number of connection to 1. So, I guess this library is not able to establish the connection to the specified port and it thinks port is not in use.

Comment: Oh! I understand now. That's unfortunate. I suppose the better solution for you in this case is to simply try to open the port - although I believe that depending on how the port was opened, this also has an edge case

Comment: If the port is opened with `SO_REUSEPORT` or `SO_REUSEADDR` then the port could be opened by more than one application - though it's unlikely that you have set this in your case. Just another edge case to consider

Comment: @DavutGürbüz I am curious to hear why you are limiting the number of connections, if you are willing to share

Comment: it's not specific to my app. There are many applications you can limit number of connections. i.e. Mirth Connect  "number of allowed connections" ,Rhapsody, :) It's a very common scenario. That's not a web sever or app server. It's a hardware communication and there is a single line. If two processes are attached to same port some undesired consequences happen

Comment: btw, even for a web server you can limit # of connections. Establishing connection doesn't guarantee learning port status. There can be other reasons you're not able to establish a connection.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz agreed that it can be limited, just not sure why someone would do it (don't think this is a hardware thing, TCP lies a few levels above the hardware, unless I'm misunderstanding your meaning) - I think a lot of people try to do this for security and I think that is generally not a good reason for such a thing - but that's not a discussion for here! Sorry this solution cause you issues, hope you're able to find one that works

Comment: @Codeblind I didn't mean to offend you, however it's not off topic. It's not related to security only. It's a requirement. TCP port used function refers to check if port in use or not and simply it returns a wrong false when server is unable to accept a new connection. If function name was canAcceptNewConnection it would be matching with what the function does. I already reported to the project owner. Just raised a flag for others to note on such cases what can happen. Thanks.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz don't worry, you are by no means offending me! You are 100% correct that it can falsely report that the port is not in use. It's good that everyone knows that. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. Just to elaborate some cases for your curiosity, I'm coding a driver for an instrument which uses serial communication and it's connected to an IoT gadget supports TCP. If two processes are attached to it it'll be a catostrophy for instrument. An ENQ character can be answered by two different attached processes... You can define this as a rare case. I'll cite another example, your web server is limited to answer N# of connections and when it reached to limit even the port is occupied portInUse will return false. What I did as a replacement is a ShellScript.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz thanks for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 5):

Thank to Steven Vachon link, I made a simple example:

```
const net = require("net");
const Socket = net.Socket;

const getNextPort = async (port) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        const socket = new Socket();

        const timeout = () =>
        {
            resolve(port);
            socket.destroy();
        };

        const next = () =>
        {
            socket.destroy();
            resolve(getNextPort(++port));
        };

        setTimeout(timeout, 10);
        socket.on("timeout", timeout);

        socket.on("connect", () => next());

        socket.on("error", error =>
        {
            if (error.code !== "ECONNREFUSED")
                reject(error);
            else
                resolve(port);
        });

        socket.connect(port, "0.0.0.0");
    });
};

getNextPort(8080).then(port => {
    console.log("port", port);
});
```

Comment: Thnks, this works

Comment: does this still work? I get all ports `"ECONNREFUSED"` but I'm able to start an http server on any of those ports. I'm on node 16.16.0

Comment: I also had some issues, fixed it for myself and since you commented on it I'll now update it here as well ;)

Comment: I'm really confused. the new code works but do you mind explaining it? If the code gets  `error.code === ECONNREFUSED` it resolves with the port???. If the code gets a `connect` the code calls `next`?

Comment: Exactly, the idea is that we are looking for a connection refused or a timeout. We basically looking for a failure in one of those two ways. Then we know the port is not used, otherwise it is and we will call `next()` to try the next one and see if it free

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get if. If we get `error.code === ECONNREFUSED` we return success. But if we were refused then doesn't that mean the port is in use? The code is calling `resolve(port)` when the connection was refused. I don't understand why that would work. That seems to opposite of what I'd expect. Am I mis-understanding?

Comment: When you get a _connection refused_ the OS simply tell you "You told me to connect to an IP with a specific PORT, but for some reason I can't" - Meaning, noting is receiving any socket on the IP:PORT. Which is what we want, we are using `0.0.0.0` with a given port. The OS can't cannot to that port, we assuming it's a free port. So we resolve, we can use that port.
Same with the timeout. Where the OS didn't received any indication if it success or failed. Since we are on the localhost, and only do the initial connection we again assuming there are no service behind it. Again, a free port

Comment: Please note that I'm solely using it for my development CLI, it's not that I've researched all the possible use cases, what cases we will have some latency, maybe a really really specific service will react differently etc.

Comment: I see my mis-understanding. I thought we were opening the port for listening. But we're not, we're trying to connect. Now it all makes sense. Thanks for putting up with me.

Answer (score 2):

this is what im doing, i hope it help someone

```
const isPortOpen = async (port: number): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let s = net.createServer();
        s.once('error', (err) => {
            s.close();
            if (err["code"] == "EADDRINUSE") {
                resolve(false);
            } else {
                resolve(false); // or throw error!!
                // reject(err); 
            }
        });
        s.once('listening', () => {
            resolve(true);
            s.close();
        });
        s.listen(port);
    });
}

const getNextOpenPort = async(startFrom: number = 2222) => {
    let openPort: number = null;
    while (startFrom < 65535 || !!openPort) {
        if (await isPortOpen(startFrom)) {
            openPort = startFrom;
            break;
        }
        startFrom++;
    }
    return openPort;
};
```

you can use `isPortOpen` if you just need to check if a port is busy or not.
and the `getNextOpenPort` finds next open port after `startFrom`. for example :

```
let startSearchingFrom = 1024;
let port = await getNextOpenPort(startSearchingFrom);
console.log(port);
```

Comment: I think the name "isPortOpen" is not describing its purpose, maybe "isPortAvailable" suites better

Answer (score 0):

check without producing an error
on mac and most unix/linux

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process')

function checkPort(port) {
  const output = spawnSync(
    `lsof -i tcp:${port} | awk '{print $2}' |grep --invert PID`,
    { shell: true }
  )
  if (output.error) {
    console.error(output.error)
    return
  }
  const pid = Buffer.from(output.stdout.buffer).toString().split('\n')[0]
  console.log({ pid })
  return pid
}

const pid = checkPort(443)
if (pid) {
  console.log(`the server is running, process id: ${pid}`)
}
```