# NodeJS function to check if a port is running or not?

Tags: node.js, sockets, port, reset, mean-stack

I am so new to NodeJS, but am trying to write a function that checks if a port to see if the port is live and running.

IF the port is running/live do nothing and check again in 3 mins. 
ELSE reset the area that the NODEjs code is in.

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible Repost of [How can I check if port is busy in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129570/how-can-i-check-if-port-is-busy-in-nodejs)

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer();

server.once('error', function(err) {
   if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
   // port is currently in use
   }
});

server.once('listening', function() {
   // close the server if listening doesn't fail
   server.close();
});

server.listen(/* put the port to check here */);
```