# Change port if specific port is already used

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, terminal

If I try to run the react app in one terminal, it opens on port 8000, and if I open a new terminal tab and try to run the app again I get the following, after which it opens the app on port 8001

```
Something is already running on port 8000.

Would you like to run the app on another port instead?(Y/n)
```

And this is possible because of:

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

Most of the solutions suggest to kill the process that occurs in the port.
But I'm trying to implement this sort of function for a Node(Express) application, such that if a particular port is running/in use, it should just open the app in another port.

I've also thought of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-port), as a solution, but this would only let me open the app either in 8000 or 8001. I want the app to be able to open on 'n' number of terminals with 'n' different ports. Essentially, is there a NodeJS alternative to *"start": "react-scripts start"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using express you can omit the `port` params when calling `app.listen`, which you make express run your app on a random unused port.

Doc: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen

EDIT:
The solution to the problem can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goldstine-8gh8q)

Comment: I had done this. I can't format the code in comment
`var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000

class Server {
  constructor(port, app) {
    this.port = port;
    this.app = app;
  }listen() {
    this.app.listen(this.port, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("App listening on port  : ", port)
      }
    });
  }
}

let server = new Server(port, app);
server.core();
server.listen();` 
I tried assigning the port to zero, but it is not assigning a random port whenever port 8000 is in use

Comment: I get an error that says 'address already in use'

Comment: It was my understanding that the port didn't matter to you, as long as the app never fails to launch. If that's the case, take a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goldstine-8gh8q?file=/src/index.js).

If you want to make a check and find a port not being used, maybe you should dig into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129570/how-can-i-check-if-port-is-busy-in-nodejs/35251815

Comment: Yes, I wanted a default port that ran, but if it is in use, it should run on any random unused port. Thank you for the reference, although the solutions provided there have not been working for me, I shall try working from there :)

Comment: Bear with me friend. I have not given up yet :)
Have you see the [portfinder](https://github.com/http-party/node-portfinder) reference there?
I could come up with the [following](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goldstine-8gh8q?file=/src/index.js). The behaviour is that every server I run goes up in the count, starting by 8000, it goes 8001, 8002, 8003...
Hope that solves it.
Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and help!! This really solved the issue I was worried about. I had gotten stuck in callback hell while I tried to use the portfinder and unnecessarily ended up confusing myself.